# Reading lines in a file, then adding until there are a certain number of lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file

I am trying to open and edit a file using Python. I need to be able to read how many lines are in the file, and if there are fewer then 5 lines add a random number from 0-10 to a separate line until there are 5 lines. This is the code I have, but it is not working, its only generating one line of text:

```
f1 = open(fname+'.txt', 'a+')    

count = 0
for line in fname:
    count = count + 1

while count < 5:
    Score = random.randint(0, 10)
    f1.write(str(Score) + str("\n"))
    count = count + 1
f1.close()
```

Comment: i think you should use `f1.readline()` instead of `fname` function to read line by line from file in for loop.

Comment: @DevangHingu - that's not needed. File objects iterate lines so the `for` loop works.

Comment: @tdelaney but how we can access `line` from `fname` variable..? i didn't unerstand.. `fname` is just filename's variable. he/she not mentioned that.

Comment: @DevangHingu - Right, the problem is that OP iterates the file name, not the file. It should be `for line in f1`.

Comment: Exacly..!!! @tdelaney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When opening a file in `append` mode, the file object’s position is at the end of the file. Which means your for loop won't run because there are no more lines to consume.
Navigate the file object’s position to the first position after opening the file:

```
import random
f1 = open('/tmp/foo.txt', 'a+')
f1.seek(0)  # Jump to the beginning of the file!
count = 0
for line in f1:  # Iterate over the file not the filename!
    count = count + 1

print(count)
while count < 5:
    Score = random.randint(0, 10)
    f1.write(str(Score) + str("\n"))
    count = count + 1
f1.close()

print(open('/tmp/foo.txt').read())
```

Out:

```
Existing line!
8
2
7
0
```

Comment: I think it would help to mention that OP was iterating the file name, not the file object. Also, it could be that the final line was not "\n" terminated and then next write will not be a new line.

Comment: Thank you. I added the seek function and changed the file name to the f1 variable and it works perfectly now!